# Octave shift with Arduino Duo and pedal shield

Tags: audio, arduino, signal-processing, pitch

I want to make a 1 or 2 octave down audio pitch shift, from a line input to an output.

Working on the pedalshield.

Instead of having only 3 position pot, I want to get:

- pot fully clock wise normal sound
- and maybe 10 steps to get 1 or 2 octave down.

Any idea? float divide?

```cpp
int in_ADC0, in_ADC1;  //variables for 2 ADCs values (ADC0, ADC1)
int POT0, POT1, POT2, out_DAC0, out_DAC1; //variables for 3 pots (ADC8, ADC9, ADC10)
int LED = 3;
int FOOTSWITCH = 7;
int TOGGLE = 2;
int a = 3;
 float c = (float)a/2;

#define MAX_DELAY 4000
uint16_t sDelayBuffer0[MAX_DELAY-1];
uint16_t sDelayBuffer1[MAX_DELAY-1];
unsigned int write_pt=0;
unsigned int read_pt_A=0, read_pt_B= MAX_DELAY/2;
unsigned int Delay_Depth, increment, divider=0, buffer0, buffer1;

void setup()
{
  //turn on the timer clock in the power management controller
  pmc_set_writeprotect(false);
  pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_TC4);

  //we want wavesel 01 with RC
  TC_Configure(TC1, 1, TC_CMR_WAVE | TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC | TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK2);
  TC_SetRC(TC1, 1, 238); // sets <> 44.1 Khz interrupt rate 109
  TC_Start(TC1, 1);

  // enable timer interrupts on the timer
  TC1->TC_CHANNEL[1].TC_IER=TC_IER_CPCS;
  TC1->TC_CHANNEL[1].TC_IDR=~TC_IER_CPCS;

  //Enable the interrupt in the nested vector interrupt controller
  //TC4_IRQn where 4 is the timer number * timer channels (3) + the channel number
  //(=(1*3)+1) for timer1 channel1
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TC4_IRQn);

  //ADC Configuration
  ADC->ADC_MR |= 0x80;   // DAC in free running mode.
  ADC->ADC_CR=2;         // Starts ADC conversion.
  ADC->ADC_CHER=0x1CC0;  // Enable ADC channels 0,1,8,9 and 10 

  //DAC Configuration
  analogWrite(DAC0,0);  // Enables DAC0
  analogWrite(DAC1,0);  // Enables DAC0
}

void loop()
{
  //Read the ADCs
  while((ADC->ADC_ISR & 0x1CC0)!=0x1CC0);// wait for ADC 0,1,8,9,10 conversion complete.
  in_ADC0=ADC->ADC_CDR[7];               // read data from ADC0
  in_ADC1=ADC->ADC_CDR[6];               // read data from ADC1 
  POT0=ADC->ADC_CDR[10];                 // read data from ADC8       
  POT1=ADC->ADC_CDR[11];                 // read data from ADC9   
  POT2=ADC->ADC_CDR[12];                 // read data from ADC10     
}

void TC4_Handler() //Interrupt at 44.1KHz rate (every 22.6us)
{
  TC_GetStatus(TC1, 1); //Clear status interrupt to be fired again.

  //Store current readings 
  sDelayBuffer0[write_pt] = in_ADC0;
  sDelayBuffer1[write_pt] = in_ADC1;

  //Adjust Delay Depth based in pot2 position.
  Delay_Depth = MAX_DELAY-1;

  //Increse/reset delay counter.
  write_pt++;
  if(write_pt >= Delay_Depth) write_pt = 0;

  out_DAC0 = ((sDelayBuffer0[read_pt_A]));
  out_DAC1 = ((sDelayBuffer1[read_pt_B]));

  if (POT0>2700)
  {
    read_pt_A = read_pt_A + 2;
    read_pt_B = read_pt_B + 2;
  }
 else if (POT0>1350)
  {
    read_pt_A = read_pt_A + 1;
    read_pt_B = read_pt_B + 1;
  }
 else
 {
   divider++;
   if (divider>=2)
   {
      read_pt_A = read_pt_A + 1;
      read_pt_B = read_pt_B + 1;
      divider=0;
    }
  }

  if(read_pt_A >= Delay_Depth) read_pt_A = 0;
  if(read_pt_B >= Delay_Depth) read_pt_B = 0;

  //Add volume control with POT2
  out_DAC0=map(out_DAC0,0,4095,1,POT2);
  out_DAC1=map(out_DAC1,0,4095,1,POT2);

  //Write the DACs
  dacc_set_channel_selection(DACC_INTERFACE, 0);       //select DAC channel 0
  dacc_write_conversion_data(DACC_INTERFACE, out_DAC0);//write on DAC
  dacc_set_channel_selection(DACC_INTERFACE, 1);       //select DAC channel 1
  dacc_write_conversion_data(DACC_INTERFACE, out_DAC1);//write on DAC
}
```